# ownCloud android, FC when scrolling file list

Tags: java, android, forceclose, owncloud

After building ownCloud from source, I get a FC when scrolling to the bottom of the file display page.

Logcat

```
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at edu.sage.cloud.DisplayUtils.getResourceId(DisplayUtils.java:147)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at edu.sage.cloud.ui.adapter.FileListListAdapter.getView(FileListListAdapter.java:118)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2123)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4684)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:2963)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3234)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5556)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1951)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1712)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1940)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1390)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2414)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1888)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5736)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3017)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2582)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:887)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2591)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
03-25 14:45:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31619):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Relative code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    if (mFiles != null && mFiles.size() > position) {
        OCFile file = mFiles.get(position);
        TextView fileName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Filename);
        String name = file.getFileName();

        fileName.setText(name);
        ImageView fileIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        fileIcon.setImageResource(DisplayUtils.getResourceId(file.getMimetype()));
        ImageView localStateView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        FileDownloaderBinder downloaderBinder = mTransferServiceGetter.getFileDownloaderBinder();
        FileUploaderBinder uploaderBinder = mTransferServiceGetter.getFileUploaderBinder();
        if (downloaderBinder != null && downloaderBinder.isDownloading(mAccount, file)) {
            localStateView.setImageResource(R.drawable.downloading_file_indicator);
            localStateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (uploaderBinder != null && uploaderBinder.isUploading(mAccount, file)) {
            localStateView.setImageResource(R.drawable.uploading_file_indicator);
            localStateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (file.isDown()) {
            localStateView.setImageResource(R.drawable.local_file_indicator);
            localStateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            localStateView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        TextView fileSizeV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.file_size);
        TextView lastModV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_mod);
        ImageView checkBoxV = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_checkbox);

        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            fileSizeV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fileSizeV.setText(DisplayUtils.bytesToHumanReadable(file.getFileLength()));
            lastModV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lastModV.setText(DisplayUtils.unixTimeToHumanReadable(file.getModificationTimestamp()));
            // this if-else is needed even thoe fav icon is visible by
            // default
            // because android reuses views in listview
            if (!file.keepInSync()) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            ListView parentList = (ListView) parent;
            if (parentList.getChoiceMode() == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE) {
                checkBoxV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                if (parentList.isItemChecked(position)) {
                    checkBoxV.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);
                } else {
                    checkBoxV.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
                }
                checkBoxV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        } else {
            fileSizeV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lastModV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkBoxV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

and:

```
public static int getResourceId(String mimetype) {

    if (mimetype == null || "DIR".equals(mimetype)) {
        return R.drawable.ic_menu_archive;

    } else {
        String[] parts = mimetype.split("/");
        String type = parts[0];
        String subtype = parts[1];

        if (TYPE_TXT.equals(type)) {
            return R.drawable.file_doc;

        } else if (TYPE_IMAGE.equals(type)) {
            return R.drawable.file_image;

        } else if (TYPE_VIDEO.equals(type)) {
            return R.drawable.file_movie;

        } else if (TYPE_AUDIO.equals(type)) {
            return R.drawable.file_sound;

        } else if (TYPE_APPLICATION.equals(type)) {

            if (SUBTYPE_PDF.equals(subtype)) {
                return R.drawable.file_pdf;

            } else if (SUBTYPES_DOCUMENT_SET.contains(subtype)) {
                return R.drawable.file_doc;

            } else if (SUBTYPES_COMPRESSED_SET.contains(subtype)) {
                return R.drawable.file_zip;
            }

        }
        // problems: RAR, RTF, 3GP are send as application/octet-stream from
        // the server ; extension in the filename should be explicitly
        // reviewed
    }

    // default icon
    return R.drawable.file;
}
```

Comment: where is line number 118 in FileListListAdapter.java ?

Comment: fileIcon.setImageResource(DisplayUtils.getResourceId(file.getMimetype()));

Comment: Do you think its because it does not recognize a file type?

Comment: yes u are right. just make a log for `String[] parts = mimetype.split("/");` and check Array Size before proceeding next

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, sorry. Could you help me out?

Comment: Also it seems to be due to a .bat file after i removed this file it worked correctly for me.

Comment: then what u want to do if file extension is .bat?

Comment: well the unkown file type should take care of this

 if (mimetype.split("/").length >= 2)
            return mimetype.split("/")[1].toUpperCase() + " file";
        return "Unknown type";